# How do I create an AWS ELB listener with frontend security policy? How do I replace the policy?

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, sdk, load-balancing

In general, this is the command I'd use:

```
my_elb = elb.create("test", { :availability_zones => ["us-east-1d"],
                              :listeners => [ { :port => 80, :protocol => "http",
                                                :instance_port => 8082, 
                                                :instance_protocol => "http" }
                                            ] } )
my_elb.listeners.create( { :port => 443, 
                           :protocol => :https, 
                           :instance_protocol => :http, 
                           :instance_port => 80, 
                           :server_certificate => cert.arn } )
```

But I can't find the syntax for adding a security policy (e.g. "ELBSecurityPolicy-2014-10")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should save the `listener` into a variable then call the `policy=` method:

```
my_elb = elb.create("test", { :availability_zones => ["us-east-1d"],
                              :listeners => [ { :port => 80, :protocol => "http",
                                                :instance_port => 8082, 
                                                :instance_protocol => "http" }
                                            ] } )
listener = my_elb.listeners.create( { :port => 443, 
                           :protocol => :https, 
                           :instance_protocol => :http, 
                           :instance_port => 80, 
                           :server_certificate => cert.arn } )

listener.policy = 'ELBSecurityPolicy-2014-10'

puts listener.policy.inspect # <AWS::ELB::LoadBalancerPolicy load_balancer_name:test name:ELBSecurityPolicy-2014-10>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on the same thing at this time and you can add the security policy into the elb.create object like I'm doing. The example below is for a VPC based ELB, as you can see in the outside of the listener you can add security groups as an array.

`webservice = elb.load_balancers.create( "webservice001",
      :listeners => [{
      :port => 80,
      :protocol => :http,
      :instance_port => 8080,
      :instance_protocol => :http 
      },
      {
      :port => 443,
      :protocol => :https,
      :instance_port => 8443,
      :instance_protocol => :https,
      :ssl_certificate_id => "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxx:server-certificate/server-certificate" 
      }],
      :subnets =>[ "subnet-id1", "subnet-id2", "subnet-id3" ],
      :security_groups => [ "webservice001-elb-sg-id#" ],
      :scheme => 'internet-facing'
  )`

Comment: He is not talking about security groups. He's talking about security policies. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/elb-security-policy-options.html

Comment: Thanks Petty T, this is something that I missed completely on my end that I also needed to define on my own script.